# Need to drop empty columns in panda data frame, dropna is not helping

Tags: python, pandas

Not able to remove empty values from panda data frame

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.NaN, regex=True)
df = df.dropna(axis="columns", how="any")
print(df)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Could you maybe show a small extract of your dataframe so we might see what could be the issue?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aUZi.png Are you asking for this?